nuxt 3 долгая загрузка dev в браузер
Получается большой водопад из 200 из кеша и кучка 304. итого 500 запросов за 20 секунд.

Пробовал так, но всеравно много запросов и долгая загрузка.
  vite: {
    server: {
      warmup: {
        clientFiles: ['@nuxt/content/dist/runtime/**/*.js', '@nuxt/ui/dist/runtime/**/*.js', '@popperjs/core/lib/**/*.js']
      }
    },
    build: {
      cssCodeSplit: false,
    }
  },

Можно ли nuxt dev сервер заставить собрать всё в node_modules в 1-10 чанков? Хочу чтоб загружалось быстрее когда обновляешь страницу.
Что то похожее на эту проблему https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/23220
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/20596
Но в другом топике её пофиксили вроде

Код "HTTP 304 Not Modified" клиента указывает, что нет необходимости повторно передавать запрошенные ресурсы. Это неявное перенаправление на кешированный ресурс. тоесть вашь код постоянно что-то пытается подгрузить?)


npm run dev в vite работает как watch вроде, если не ошибаюсь) тоесть в режиме постоянной проверки кода на изменения) и если такие были, то перекомпил...


да, я знаю что это 304, но этих 304 очень много

у вас в проекте, предположим, 200 файлов JS) Когда происходит сборка проекта, там будет 1-3 сжатых файла которые не изменяются) в dev режиме, файлы не собираются в один, а загружаются каждый в отдельности, при этом обновляются они тоже автоматически если изменить код в редакторе) Проверьте поведение приложения при dev и build | prod режимах, по скриншоту как раз .vue в 304 попадают, остальное в кеше уже) что касается собрать все node_modules в один файл.. даже не знаю, разный модуль вызывается с разного файла, а если сборка не собрана.. p.s. 22 сек на загрузку конечно страшно))

к примеру, VScode в режиме remote выжирает у удаленного сервера примерно гигабайт+ ОЗУ и не плохо грузит проц) тут ситуация схожая... + если там же запустить dev (watch) режим у проекта, то 2 ГБ озу сервера улетают сразу, без шансов

По советам из исуй добился загрузки 5 сек
